# Download html page containing image to a pdf using jspdf and html2canvas

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, jspdf, html2canvas

**Actual Problem**

I am using **jspdf** and **htmltocanvas** to create a PDF in **Python-Flask**.
We have some html text with image and would like to download that to a pdf on a button click. I have done a jsfiddle to show this, when we click on the Print button, pdf gets downloaded but the text is coming out as stretched and the logo image is not showing up.
Pls check the code in jsfiddle, not able to understand what is causing it to not show the image and stretch the text characters in downloaded pdf.

**What i have done**

Following is the jsfiddle link for the code :-

http://jsfiddle.net/qcLkud1e/

```
var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
function add_logo(doc){
    return doc.addImage($('img').attr('src'),90,0,120,40);
}

$("#printtopdf").on('click',function(){
    doc.save('Invoice.pdf');
});

html2canvas($(".wrapper"),
{ allowTaint: true,
    useCORS: false,
    onrendered:function(canvas)
    {
        var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        doc.addImage(dataUrl,0,0,300,210);
        doc = add_logo(doc);
    }
});
```

**Expected Output**
[image: Expected Output Screenshot]